# LXC Is it possible to run a 12.04 container on 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, lxc

Other than the kernel only, is it possible to emulate an older install of Ubuntu?

I looked in `/usr/share/lxc/templates` and it only has "lxc-ubuntu".

Answer (score -1):

A little more info, this fixed my problem:

```
sudo lxc-create -t download -n [YOURNEWCONTAINERNAME] -- --dist ubuntu --release precise --arch amd64
```

I figured this out by reading the template script. There's probably other options available.

Comment: A little more info such as, "this command does X and it fixed my problem"?